# Using the MS Graph to upload a file to a SharePoint library that is over the threshold where the file already exists

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to upload a file to a SharePoint library where the number of items in the library exceeds the threshold (5000).

When creating an [upload session for a resumable upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession)...

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{itemId}/createUploadSession
```

...this works perfectly well *except* when the file already exists, then I am presented with a 404.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "The resource could not be found.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "6f31b3ee-2003-43aa-8956-99c82367c770",
            "date": "2018-02-13T01:29:41"
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/items/{itemId}/createUploadSession
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}/createUploadSession
```

The documentation says to *Handle 404 Not Found errors when doing resumable uploads by starting the entire upload over. This indicates the upload session no longer exists.* But I am getting the error when attempting to create the upload session, so I don't believe this statement to be true.

This still occurs when `"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename"` is set in the body.

If I switch to using the [standard upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_put_content)...

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content
```

... it will overwrite the file without error, except that the maximum file size is 4MB, which is pretty limiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There turned out to be an issue in OneDrive for Business that triggered the behavior you were observing. A fix should now be deployed, so hopefully you can upload into large folders now... definitely let us know if you're still seeing issues.

Comment: Thank you, I had forgotten to mention that I have since tested this in our environment and can confirm it is resolved.